# Ionic : cordova is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to use [InAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/), I install this plugin, and use it in controller like :-

```
myApp.controller('en', function($scope , $ionicLoading , $http  , $stateParams  ,$cordovaInAppBrowser) {

    $scope.PDFNotNull = true;
    $scope.iframeLoadedCallBack = function(){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
    }

    $scope.read = function() {
           cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.tafseer.info/phocadownload/copy_of_the_book/khatima.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');
    };  

});
```

But its show me in console this error:-

```
ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at l.$scope.read (en.js:22)
```

Where is problem

Comment: you aren't following the format shown in the documentation you listed.  it should be `$cordovaInAppBrowser.open`.

Comment: i put it in function parameter ,,,

Comment: not sure what that means?

Comment: i try           `$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://www.tafseer.info/phocadownload/copy_of_the_book/khatima.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');` and sam error

Comment: you changed it to `$cordovaInAppBrowser` and you still got an error that `cordova is not defined`?  That makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: see this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Comment: ok well that's not the same plugin as the code you listed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install ngCordova for this?
Use `$cordovaInAppBrowser.open()` after you will install ngCordova. It should work fine. In other way try to reinstall plugin.